# Check if number has opted out in twilio

Tags: python, django, twilio, sms, twilio-api

I am building a web application that needs to be able to send SMS messages and check if a number has opted out of SMS. The only option that I have found is to use a web-hook for SMS replies and check there.
I am looking for an option where I can just ping the API and check if a number has been opted-out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opt-outs are handled on your side, so you will need to keep track when opt-out keywords are sent toward your application and if so, update your CRM to remove the consumers mobile number from receiving future SMS.

If you attempt to send an SMS to an opted-out consumer, you will receive an error message from Twilio.

[ERROR - 21610 - Attempt to send to unsubscribed recipient](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/21610)

[Twilio support for opt-out keywords (SMS STOP filtering)](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223134027-Twilio-support-for-opt-out-keywords-SMS-STOP-filtering-)

"These messages will also be delivered to your Twilio account, and the defined web hook, so you can update your application logic."